# Error establishing a database connection on my newly hosted wp website

Tags: wordpress, hosting

I am  in a difficult situation..I dont have knowledge in hosting websites so far. I have developed a wordpress website and trying to host it in the presently woking server with a working domain. before it was a static website. the host provider is www.networksolutions.com.. what i did for hosting was,

```
1. exported database from a fully working website in local server (xampp).
2. exported database file is opened with dreamweaver and edited localhost and repalce with my domain name (www.abc.com) say..
3.edited wp_config file like below 

   define('DB_NAME', 'my_db');

  /** MySQL database username */
  define('DB_USER', 'my_usernm'); //before 'root'

  /** MySQL database password */
 define('DB_PASSWORD', 'my_pass'); //before null

  /** MySQL hostname */
  define('DB_HOST', 'www.abc.com'); //before 'localhost'

    4.uploaded database file in to web server and transfer the website folder in /htdocs using filezilla

 5.Redifined the domain pointing to old folder to my new folder jst uploaded
  www.oldabc.com -> htdocs/
   www.abc.com -> htdocs/abc/ <-here abc folder contains the whole files and  folders of my wordpress site.

 6. databse is uploaded sucsessfully but dont know how to link with    thespecific ftp account/folder.  I have put the username and password in  wp_config file same like ausername and   password for uploading the database to the phpmyadmin host window.
```

please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may be here:

/** MySQL hostname */
  define('DB_HOST', 'www.abc.com'); //before 'localhost'

Databases are almost always hosted at 'localhost' not at you domain.

Try reverting to:

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

MORE DETAILED ANSWER

1. I suggest you create a default installation of WP -- including a stock database -- at NetworkSolutions. That will take care of configuring everything: site url, site home, database user, dbase pw, etc.
2. Download your theme from your local install, and upload it to the new site.
3. Then in your existing local WP install, go to Admin > Tools > Export and select everything you want to export to the new site.
4. Go to the new site, Admin > Tools > Import, and import what you exported. Using the WP import/export should eliminate overwriting anything in the new database that should not be overwritten by your local install (site url, home url, users, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! The thing is that I cant make any database user through phpmyadmin panel provided by the hosting website. its throwing no privilege error.We have to create at least one user right?

Comment: I suggest you create a default installation of WP -- including a stock database -- at NetworkSolutions. That will take care of configuring everything: site url, site home, database user, dbase pw, etc.

Comment: Ok.Thanks a lot.. I will check it out!

Comment: Hi Friend, When I changed the host name to the IP address of the server, the website is loaded, but only links are there. no slider no images no menu etc..what will be the reason ?

Comment: Could be a problem with the home_url() and site_url() as set in WP. If you can get to phpmyadmin, look in the wp_options table and make sure the home url and site url entries match your current domain. If not, update them. You can also change these values in other ways (https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL) but changing in DB via phpmyadmin is best.

Comment: An easy way to check if the site_url/home_url is the problem is this. Go to your site, view the source of the homepage, and click the link to your style.css page. It will be in the header. Just search for "style.css." if you click the URL for the style.css link and it's not found, your site and home urls are not correct.